# Vector Subscript out of range error.The error occurs even if the vector has greater index than the index for which data is accessed

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, range, tokenize

I am using VC++ 2013.I'm trying to access the index of the vector where it shows vector subscript out of range.My code is given below:

```
std::string str="1,2,3, 4 , 0.00000 , ";
 vector<string>veclist;
 veclist=(tokenize(str,","));
 //Now the veclist has a size of 6.But when i am trying to access it through;
 long num=stol(veclist.at(4));
```

The code crashes and shows vector subscript out of range.I don't know why the code crashes and what's the error in this!!!

Comment: You have a vector of longs vector<long>veclist;. So this call  long num=stol(veclist.at(4)); does not make sense. because the function stol expects an object of the type std::string. Maybe there is a typo and you need a vector of strings.

Comment: Vlad,its actually a vector of string.Its a mistake that i mentioned it as long vector.But changed later.

Comment: Then search the reason in the function tokenize.

Comment: How do you know that you have 6 elements? Check the size of `veclist` for me.

Comment: As the string is tokenized based on commas, it has a size of 6 and i verified it.

Comment: Will the change of tokenize function to wxtokenize function resolves the issue?,Vlad

Comment: Where's your [MCVE]?

Answer (score 0):

> The code crashes and shows vector subscript out of range.I don't know
>   why the code crashes and what's the error in this!!!

The message tells you all.

It crashes since you have no rights to access `veclist.at(4)`. Simply you have not enough elements in `veclist` or `veclist` is empty.

Check the number elements in `veclist` by `veclist.size()` after executing `(tokenize(str,","));`

**Edit:**

You may have different problem then reported. Your `str` tokens may not be liked by the `stol` function. That can cause the crash.

Consider this test program. I have written `tokenize_split` which should match yours.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

std::vector<std::string> tokenize_split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    std::vector<string> tokens;
    while (getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        tokens.push_back(item);
    }
    return tokens;
}

int main(void)
{
   std::string str1="1 2 3 4 5 6";
   std::string str2="1,2,3, 4 , 0.00000 , "; // Your string
   std::string str3="1,2,3,4,5,6";

   vector<string> veclist;
   long num; 

   veclist = tokenize_split(str3, ',');
   std::cout <<  "Size= " << veclist.size() << endl;
   std::cout <<  "Token= " << "<" << veclist.at(4) << ">"  << endl;
   num = std::stol(veclist.at(4));
   std::cout << "Number " << num  << endl << endl;

   veclist = tokenize_split(str2, ',');
   std::cout << "Size= " << veclist.size() << endl;
   std::cout <<  "Token= " << "<" << veclist.at(4) << ">"  << endl;
   num = std::stol(veclist.at(4));
   std::cout << "Number " << num  << endl << endl;

   veclist = tokenize_split(str1, ' ');
   std::cout <<  "Size= " << veclist.size() << endl;
   std::cout <<  "Token= " << "<" << veclist.at(4) << ">"  << endl;
   num = std::stol(veclist.at(4));
   std::cout << "Number " << num  << endl << endl;

   veclist = tokenize_split(str2, ' ');
   std::cout << "Size= " << veclist.size() << endl;
   std::cout <<  "Token= " << "<" << veclist.at(4) << ">"  << endl;
   num = std::stol(veclist.at(4));
   std::cout << "Number " << num  << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
Size= 6                                                                                                                                      
Token= <5>                                                                                                                                   
Number 5                                                                                                                                     

Size= 6                                                                                                                                      
Token= < 0.00000 >                                                                                                                           
Number 0

Size= 6                                                                                                                                        
Token= <5>                                                                                                                                     
Number 5                                                                                                                                       

Size= 5                                                                                                                                        
Token= <,>                                                                                                                                     
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'                                                                         
  what():  stol                                                                                                                                
Aborted
```

Program crashes since your string `str2` does not contain a valid number that could be successfully converted to `long` by the `stol` function. The token `','` will cause the abort.

Comment: No,I have enough elements in veclist and thats why I am confused with this error.

Comment: @KawinAnto Could you check `std::cout  << veclist.size()` for me after executing `(tokenize(str,","));`?

Comment: yeah @sg7....I checked it after tokenizing the string..It is 6...Even i added a check line(if veclist.size()==6) before accessing it.

Comment: @KawinAnto: _"No,I have enough elements in veclist"_ This cannot be so. Your assumption/observation has been shown to be false. Check it in more detail.